# Invoking a php script from java applet?

Tags: java, php, applet, invoke

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RegisterUser extends Applet{



TextField panel1 = new TextField(10);
TextField panel2 = new TextField(10);
TextField panel3 = new TextField(10);
Button    save   = new Button("Save");



public void init(){

    add(panel1);
    add(new Label("Name:"));
    addNewLine();
    add(panel2);
    add(new Label("Last:"));
    addNewLine();
    add(save);
    addNewLine();



save.addActionListener(new SaveListener());
}

class SaveListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

    URL myURL = new URL("http://myplace/2272/save.php");
        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.connect();


}
}


private void addHorizontalLine(Color c)
{
  Canvas line = new Canvas( );
  line.setSize(10000,1);
  line.setBackground(c);
  add(line);
}


private void addNewLine( )
{
  addHorizontalLine(getBackground( ));
}

 }
```

The code above is a java applet. That is a GUI  for name last name email enterence.It has a button. I want to call a php script -save.php- when the button is clicked. I tried it in my actionPerformed method but it doesnt work.

How can i do it.

Here is my php script below

```
<?php
session_start();

$fp = fopen('users.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, "\nname: " . $_GET["name"] . "\n");
fwrite($fp, "last name: " . $_GET["last_name"] . "\n");
fwrite($fp, "email: " . $_GET["email"] . "\n");

fclose($fp);
$_SESSION['registered']=1;
header( 'Location: http://myplace2272/save.php' ) ;
?>
```

I m not sure that the script is also correct?

The applet works properly without php script invocation.

Answer (score 3):

When you call save.php you need to pass parameters with it:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://myplace/2272/save.php?name="+panel1.getText()+"&last_name="+panel2.getText()+"&email="+panel3.getText());
```

Comment: Could you offer a document for this

Comment: Sorry, I'm new new in java. A little bit confused.What is the mean of Your first line? save.php?name=aaa&last_name=bbb&email=ccccc. I modified the code but it doesnt compile.

Comment: @roll This is the name of the php page and the parameters being sent to it. You need to fill the values with your data on the Java side.